# Âmbito tempo no tempo perfeito

Tags: tempo-verbal

Dizem [algumas fontes](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/12292400) que o tempo pretérito perfeito composto se utiliza para as ações recorrentes. Porém, quanto tempo tem que passar até uma ação poder ser chamada "recorrente"? Veja o exemplo seguinte:

> [***Tem chovido*** vs ***Choveu***] muito esta semana!

Qual tempo se prefere neste caso? Será que a chuva não precisa de tempo suficiente (uma semana) para ser chamada "recorrente", ou podemos usar o tempo perfeito? Em palavras simples; **qual é o ponto de corte para o tempo perfeito**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O significado não difere muito entre ambas as formas verbais e é muito frequente serem usadas para dizer a mesma coisa.

No entanto, de um ponto de vista mais *formal* trata-se de uma distinção entre uma acção *continuada* e uma acção *finita*, mais do que uma questão de recorrência.

No exemplo apresentado:

> **Tem chovido** muito esta semana!

[Trata-se de uma acção continuada.](http://www.linguateca.pt/Diana/download/portugisisk.html#Preterito_perfeito_composto_do_indicativo_PPC) O verbo **chover** é precedido do verbo auxiliar **ter**. É análogo ao ***continuous past*** do inglês (e outras línguas).

Por outro lado,

> **Choveu** muito esta semana!

[É uma acção finita.](http://www.linguateca.pt/Diana/download/portugisisk.html#Usos_apenas_do_Perfeito) Como se tivesse **chovido** e parado de **chover**. Análogo ao ***past perfect*** do inglês.

---

Como nas referências apresentadas não está muito claro, vou tentar esclarecer melhor a questão da **continuidade** /  **recorrência** / **intervalo de tempo**.

Usa-se a forma composta (pretérito perfeito composto) quando uma acção:

1. começou há algum tempo atrás (não importa quando) e continua a ocorrer no presente;
2. ocorreu no passado e previsivelmente vai ocorrer novamente no presente ou futuro imediato.

Exemplos:

> **Tem chovido** muito esta semana.
> **Tem nevado** muito este mês.
> **Têm morrido** muitos artistas este ano.

Usa-se o pretérito perfeito (simples) quando uma acção:

1. começou **e** acabou no passado (não importa se passado próximo ou distante).

Exemplos:

> **Choveu** muito esta semana.
> **Nevou** muito em 2012.
> **Morreram** muitos artistas este ano.

Comment: Boa resposta. Agora entendo; trata-se da natureza da açao (se for finita/continuada), mais do que a quantidade do tempo decorrido. Obg!

Answer (score 8):

O Pretérito Perfeito Composto não tem necessariamente de exprimir iteração; dependendo das características aspetuais do predicado, pode ter um valor durativo (nomeadamente, se se tratar de um *estado*). Por exemplo:

> **Tem chovido** [=tem estado a chover] a tarde inteira.

A diferença com *choveu a tarde inteira* é essencialmente que *tem chovido* só pode ser proferida se ainda for de tarde e ainda estiver a chover (portanto a ação tem de continuar até ao presente).

Mas passando à tua pergunta, quantas repetições são necessárias, a resposta é depende; podem ser só duas. Os únicos requerimentos são:

- Durante o tempo de tópico (que pode ser explicitamente delimitado com *desde Janeiro*, *nos últimos dias*, etc.), o período em que ação ocorreu tem de ser longo o suficiente, o número de repetições grande o suficiente e as repetições distribuídas pelo período de tempo bem o suficiente para que **se possa estabelecer um padrão/hábito**.
- O número de repetições não pode ser especificado: **Tenho-a visitado vinte vezes*, mas é possível *tenho-a visitado várias/muitas/poucas vezes* e *tenho-a visitado três vezes por semana* (o que é iterado é visitar três vezes por semana).

Repara que o facto de haver um padrão não implica que ação seja frequente:

> **Tenho visitado** os meus pais a cada três anos.

Quanto a *tem chovido/choveu muito esta semana*, é um mau exemplo — trata-se de frases ambíguas. Podemos estar a falar da frequência *(= muitas vezes)* ou da quantidade/intensidade *(=muita chuva)*. Diria que a interpretação preferencial com *tem chovido* é de frequência, e com *choveu* de quantidade. Se for de quantidade para os dois casos, *tem chovido* tem um carácter mais iterativo. Qualquer que seja a interpretação, *tem chovido* só pode ser usado se estivermos algures no meio da semana e *choveu* só pode ser usado se estivermos no fim da semana ou já na semana seguinte (*esta semana* = *esta última semana*) — se estivermos a meio da semana só podemos usar *choveu* com algo do género ***já** choveu muito esta semana*.

Em suma, para o Pretérito Perfeito Composto é preciso que que haja um início indeterminado de um estado ou de uma série de eventos no passado que se mantenha até ao presente e que possa continuar depois deste. Já o Simples é «*terminativo*, isto é, marca um momento em que um estado ou um evento terminou, podendo só nos casos em que há culminação inferir-se um estado consequente» (*Gramática do Português* de Maria Mateus e outras, 6.ª ed., p. 156).

Comment: Isto sem abordar os raros casos em que o pretérito perfeito composto não tem estes valores, como em «tenho dito» e quando o tempo de referência não corresponde ao tempo da enunciação.